# rvm install 1.9.3 on OS X 10.9.5 failing

Tags: rvm

Trying to install ruby 1.9.3 using rvm on Mac OSX 10.9.5. I've installed latest command line tools. I'm getting some weird errors with miniruby. I tried following other instructions to use clang but that didn't help:

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang

ruby-1.9.3-p547 - #removing src/ruby-1.9.3-p547..
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' are already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Warning: found user selected compiler 'clang', this will suppress RVM auto detection mechanisms.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/redact/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p547 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p547, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p547 - #extracting ruby-1.9.3-p547 to /Users/redact/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p547....
ruby-1.9.3-p547 - #applying patch /Users/redact/.rvm/patches/ruby/GH-488.patch.
ruby-1.9.3-p547 - #configuring...............................................
ruby-1.9.3-p547 - #post-configuration.
ruby-1.9.3-p547 - #compiling...........................
Error running '__rvm_make -j 1',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/redact/.rvm/log/1412548428_ruby-1.9.3-p547/make.log
-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

* Loaded script: ./miniruby

* Loaded features:

    0 enumerator.so

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a lot of research and eventually found some hints to a solution here: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1975

I had to install a different version of gcc and run rvm using that:

```
brew install gcc46 # wait a long long time. 
CC=$( find $( brew --prefix gcc46 ) -name gcc-4.6 -perm /u+x ) rvm install 1.9.3
```

Hope this helps someone.